# WebSocket connection established, but can't receive messages

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I've written a short WebSocket example server in PHP yesterday. When the client connects to the server, the server reads the client Handshake and sends the server Handshake back with the appropriate key. onopen() of the client gets fired and the server and client *seem* to be connected.

My problem is: The server can't receive client messages and the client can't receive server messages. onmessage() wasn't triggered once and socket_select() never gives back the client that sent the message on server side.

```js
function connect() {
    try {
        var webSocketURL = "ws://" + serverAddress + ":" + serverPort;
        socket = new WebSocket(webSocketURL);

        socket.onopen = function() {
            log("Connected! (" + this.readyState + ")");
        }

        socket.onclose = function() {
            log("Closed! (" + this.readyState + ")");
            socket.close();
        }

        socket.onerror = function(error) {
            log("Error: " + error.data);
            socket.close();
        }

        socket.onmessage = function(message) {
            log("Message from server: " + message.data);
        }
    }

    catch (e) {
        alert("Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

The server code is a bit longer, but you can find it [here](http://pastebin.com/sxiVEuqQ).

Can anyone tell me what's wrong there? Is the handshake incorrect?

Client output:

> Connected! (1)
>   Message to server: 0USERchannel

[Server output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKaEP.png).

Help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you figure it out in the end? Same problem here

Answer (score 1):

On client side, enshure your `socket` variable is global.

Comment: var socket; is at the top of my script, I guess this is accessable from everywhere.